# C++: Re-use line printed to console

Tags: c++, terminal, console, formatting, output

Edit: Thanks to user mah's comment, I found what I was looking for. I want to **rollback the line**, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277058/how-to-rollback-lines-from-cout).

---

I always print information to the console using `std::cout` and `std::endl`, but when printing the progress of a loop this becomes quickly very crowded:

> 98.3968 % complete
>
> 98.5972 % complete
>
> 98.7976 % complete
>
> 98.998 % complete
>
> 99.1984 % complete
>
> 99.3988 % complete
>
> 99.5992 % complete
>
> 99.7996 % complete

The linux program [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) for instance does this in a much nicer way, even constructing a progress bar consisting of equal (=) signs:[image: Example output of wget]

How can this or something similar be done in C++? Are there some nice libraries? I guess some terminal GUI libraries could do that, but I don't need the "**user**" part in "User Interface", I only want to print information in a better way.

Comment: Don't use std::endl (or `\n`). Use `\r` instead.

Comment: (You *do* need the user part. After all, the output is for the user...)

Comment: @mah Thanks I did not know about `\n`, this looks much better already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either print the "="s without a line break or you can use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) which I think also wget uses.

But in my opinion ncurses is much work to do. For small Projects I recommend the simpler way.