# How would I overwrite a printed 2D array to simulate 'updates'

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So given a 2D array called 'world' and the code below to output the array to the console. I want to constantly update the outputted array using a while loop to simulate movement and other actions via changes in the array values without it messily reprinting the entire thing for every update.

I would imagine the best way to do this would be to try and reset the output stream to the first line and overwrite the previous printed array each update but I am unsure on how to do this.

```
char world[20][20];
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < std::size(world); row++)
{
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < std::size(world); col++) 
    {
        std::cout << world[row][col];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Post more code - particularly the definition of `world`.

Comment: `char world[20][20];`

Comment: Shouldn't the `col < std::size(world)` be `col < std::size(world[row])`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rollback lines from cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277058/how-to-rollback-lines-from-cout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this on one line, using `\r` with `printf`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337529/how-to-update-a-printed-message-in-terminal-without-reprinting-linux). However, I'm not certain this is easy if one wishes to reprint multiple lines, as you do.

A better suggestion would be to make use of something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which seems to be designed for your purposes, and was probably used to make other programs you've seen operate this way.